# variable counter in php

Tags: php, variables, loops, count

Good day, I was tasked to make a variable counter in php. 
Im stuck at the last stage.  And that is to display the total number of positive values. I used the count() in php, but it's not giving me the total number. is there a way that i can get the summation of the value that is is count()?

```
  if ($start < $end)
    {
    for($ctr = $start; $ctr<=$end; $ctr++)
    {

    if ($ctr == 0)
    {
      echo " <br/ >there is a zero <br/ >"; 
    }   

    else if ($ctr <=0)
    {
    echo count($ctr) . " negative value" ;
    }
    else if($ctr >=0)
    {
    echo count($ctr) . " positive value ";
    }

    }
```

Comment: Do you know what `count()` *does*? http://php.net/count

Comment: Count is used for arrays.

Comment: `else if ($ctr <=0)` could be `else if ($ctr < 0)` here. Same for "greater than".

Comment: may be you need `$ctr-$start+1` ?

Comment: @sal00m we are here to say that. Not everyone knows everything

Comment: i see. i'm sorry im just new to php. thank you for taking time to review my question.

Comment: Especially if you're new, please get used to reading the manual. Always. Search for things in it. Read what functions do. The documentation is the single most important tool in a programmer's arsenal. http://php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$zero = $pos = $neg = 0;
for($ctr = $start; $ctr<=$end; $ctr++)
{
   switch(true){
     case $ctr==0: $zero++; break;
     case $ctr<0:  $neg++;  break;
     case $ctr>0:  $pos++;  break;
   }
}
if($zero)
  echo "there is a zero<br/>"; 
if($pos)
  echo "$pos positive values<br/>" ;
if($neg)
  echo "$neg negative values<br/>" ;
```

---

Better way is without any loop:

```
function test($start, $end) {
    echo "Test of [$start, $end]:\n";
    if ($isThereZero = $start * $end <= 0) {
        echo "There is zero\n";
    }

    if ($start < 0) {
        $negatives = $isThereZero ? -$start : -$start+$end;
        echo "$negatives negative values\n";
    }
    if ($end > 0) {
        $positives = $isThereZero ? $end : $end - $start;
        echo ($positives)." positive values\n";
    }
}
test(-12, 5);
test(-12, -5);
test(5, 12);
test(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
$zer = 0;
$pos = 0;
$neg = 0;
if ($start < $end)
{
  for($ctr = $start; $ctr<=$end; $ctr++)
  {
    if ($ctr == 0)
    {
      $zer++; 
    }   

    else if ($ctr < 0)
    {
      $neg++;
    }
    else if($ctr > 0)
    {
      $pos++;
    }
}

echo $zer . " zero value" ;
echo $neg . " negative value" ;
echo $pos . " positive value ";
```

Comment: A counter for "zero" seems a bit useless

Comment: @user2841984 if answer suits to your needs, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this could be done without a loop. This is a bit tricky and also a bit far from the initial question :

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/qdBswj9u)**

```
$start = -3;
$end = 5;

echo ($start <= 0 && $end >= 0 ? "1" : "0")." zero value\n";
echo ($start < 0 && $start <= $end ? (-$start-($end > -1 ? 0 : -$end-1)) : "0"). " negative value\n";
echo ($end > 0 && $start <= $end ? ($end-($start < 1 ? 0 : $start-1)) : "0"). " positive value\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else if($ctr >=0)
{
  $cnt++; //or $cnt+=1;
 }
```

Then use $cnt++ for no of count for positive vales